# Update: Replace content with inner content in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

i have an html element in my database and i would like to replace it with its inner content.

Currently the content looks like this:

```
<h2><a rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" class="chartbeat-section" name="title">title</a></h2>
```

And i would like to get rid of the a-tags, so that the outcome would look like this:

```
<h2>title</h2>
```

Is that somehow possible in sql?

Comment: It might be possible, but why do this in SQL? There are other techniques that are much better for this task. Example: jQuery, XSLT, DOM manipulation. It's generally common practice to keep the data tasks (SQL) separate from the presentation tasks.

Comment: actually i was working for a customer with an old wordpres plugin that did this inside of the sql database and i would like to clean it up for SEO reasons :)

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` report when you run it in a MySQL client?

Comment: It shows 10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1

Comment: `<h2><a rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" class="chartbeat-section" name="title">title</a></h2>
` Is this hardcoded in the database? Or do parts of it vary, such as `<h2>` and `title`?

Comment: "... with an old wordpres plugin that did this inside of the sql database" and now it stopped working ? suddenly, without sharing the code that was use in the old plugin, without ANY reason why this old plugin is no longer working in mariadb 10.5..... (sigh).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it this way:

```
set @html = '<h2><a rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" class="chartbeat-section" name="title">title</a></h2>';

select regexp_replace(@html, '<a [^>]*>([^<]*)</a>', '\\1') AS _result;
```

Output:

```
<h2>title</h2>
```

Tested on MariaDB 10.5: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=6bc5fa7e887729d12231415910860c46

Read about the REGEXP_REPLACE() function in MariaDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/

Please don't ask "now what if it's like ...". I have demonstrated the technique. It's up to you to turn that into knowledge and apply it to other cases.